# How can I detect a URL redirect that is not supported curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using URLResolver from https://github.com/mattwright/URLResolver.php

The $site from the following code is added by a user. This code has worked perfectly for months until the a user added `http://adsactly.city`. There are other sites that redirect and the code has always worked perfectly.

This particular site however - just hangs until a 504 error is returned (gateway timeout).

I understand the error, what I don't understand is why its hanging on this url and because I don't know what is causing this to happen, I don't know how exactly to fix it.

If I visit the site in question it redirects to `https://steemitgoldminer.com/S-City/`. The redirected site works perfectly - but obviously I can't change user input.

I have attempted to do a wget on the url and it also just hangs, which leads me to believe it is not a javascript redirect nor a meta redirect (perhaps I am wrong?).

So my questions are why is this URL having a 504 timeout and more importantly how do I go about detecting this type of redirect so I can test for it in the future?

```
$site = 'http://adsactly.city';

require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/classes/parse_urls/URLResolver.php');

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNBINARYOPTION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com/1');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$resolver = new URLResolver();
$resolve= $resolver->resolveURL($site);
$resolved = $resolve->getURL();
$parsing = file_get_contents_curl($resolved);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($parsing);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$para = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');

echo $resolved; die;
```

Comment: Try setting some higher value for `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: I have attempted setting both options to 500 but it still times out.

Comment: When I test the url with facebook it is able to get the site in less than 1 second, so what are they doing that I can't seem to be able to. I am completely baffled as to whats going on.

Comment: May be they don't want you to crawl their site? Also this variable `$curl` seems undefined